# Calculating correct coordinates

Tags: php, html, imagemap

I'm exporting a file which contains imagemap coordinates for links.

For example:

```
<string geometry="Left=649;Top=118;Right=739;Bottom=188" ..>
<string geometry="Left=495;Top=118;Right=600;Bottom=188" ..>
```

Since the program exports a 'zoomlevel' (which is 113%) I need to recalculate the correct coordinates; based on the zoomlevel, and real the realsize of the image (780x1134).

What is the correct way to calculate such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the original values are at 100% zoom and 113% is enlarging it by 13%, all you need to do is multiply the coords by 1.13 to get the 113%

Comment: Perfect answer. I couldn't come up with this.. time for a coffee break ;-)